# How to automate some web interaction with a headless browser?

Tags: javascript, node.js, powershell, automation, browser-automation

I want to create a script to do certain actions on a web page on a schedule. I know there are browser extensions such as Greasemonkey or Selenium that I can use but my requirement is that the script should run from a command prompt. My preferences are PowerShell and NodeJS, or any .NET solution. One thing I was wondering was is it possible to record some web interaction in a [.HAR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.har) file and then execute it, or is the .HAR format only used for logging network traffic and cannot be re-run? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not limited by the browser type I think that the [PowerShell](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_PowerShell) is the best choice.

It covers all your requirements, like

> create a script to do certain actions on a web page on a schedule.

and

> the script should run from a command prompt.

and its a

> .NET solution.

Since it is developed for task automation and configuration management. Consisting of a command-line shell and associated scripting language built on the .NET Framework. Also provides full access to both local and remote systems and network devices.

I have such scripts in these my articles - [custom script #1](http://automationisking.blogspot.com/2014/08/where-is-my-automation-level.html?m=1) and [custom script #2](http://automationisking.blogspot.com/2014/04/custom-continuous-integration-testing.html?m=1).

The [Windows Task schedular](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Task_Scheduler) will manage the launch of your scripts at pre-defined times or after specified time intervals.

***Update***

About the jQuery injection in PowerShell script you can try one of these:

- [post #1](http://mac-blog.org.ua/powershell-ie-open-page-inject-jquery-run-code/)
- [post #2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4058669/powershell-using-jquery-through-internetexplorer-application)

Comment: Yup, that's what I ended up doing. However, I have trouble running JQuery on the page. I created these questions for it: [(1)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26021813/450913) [(2)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26023915/450913)

Comment: I couldn't do it by self too back then, so I just had to use the JS support of IE COM. However please see my updated answer, maybe it will be helpful to you.

Comment: Thanks. Also see my solution here for running JavaScript/jQuery in PowerShell and receive results back from the web page: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26046039/450913

Comment: Link in "custom script #1", "custom script #2" are broken so are "post #1", "post #2" and "post #3". Requesting @ekostadinov to update the hyperlinks to keep the answer helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I've never seen a tool to execute a .HAR file directly, although there is enough information in a HAR file that you could write a tool to parse it and replay some of the requests.

The approach I would use, however, is to either write a shell script that executes cURL commands that perform the actions you need (in Chrome you can get a cURL command for a request from the network tab of the developer tools), or if the interaction is too complex, try writing a PhantomJS script that can do what you need.