# Accessing JavaScript Global Object from IE COM

Tags: internet-explorer, powershell, com, global, internet-explorer-11

Looking at [Compatibility changes in IE11](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/bg182625(v=vs.85).aspx), we have that [window.execScript](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536420(v=vs.85).aspx) is replaced with [eval](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkId=303948). Now when using the IE COM object how can we get hold of the [JavaScript Global Object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/52f50e9t(v=vs.94).aspx) that has the eval function?

PowerShell:

```
$ie = New-Object -COM InternetExplorer.Application
$document = $ie.document
$window = $document.parentWindow
# How to get JavaScript Global Object from these?
```

See also this related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26021813/450913).

Comment: That would be [`IHTMLDocument::get_Script`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752642.aspx), I believe. You would need to call `eval` via late binding.

Comment: I can't find any properties in `$ie.Document.Script` that points to the JavaScript Global Object. Do you have an example of using it using PowerShell or WSH? Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean, points to? The `IDispatch*` that `IHTMLDocument::get_Script` returns **is** the global object. I'm not familiar with PowerShell. In WSH, just simply `ie.Document.Script.eval('alert("Hi")')` should work.

Comment: Running `$ie.Document.Script.eval('alert("Hi")')` I get this error: Method invocation failed because [System.__ComObject] does not contain a method named 'eval'

Comment: Apparently, for late binding in PowerShell, you need to do something like [this](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2010/12/14/dynamic-method-invocation-in-powershell.aspx) (but recall that I don't really know what I'm talking about). WHS runs JavaScript or VBScript, which use late binding natively.

Comment: OK, so the article says we can do this: `$window."alert".Invoke("Hi")` or this `$ie.document.Script."alert".Invoke("Hi")` which works! In case of `eval`, however, this doesn't work: `$ie.document.Script."eval".Invoke('alert("Hi")')` Error: You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61866/discussion-between-orad-and-igor-tandetnik).